# Faking click referrer in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Is it technically possible to FAKE website’s link click referrer when using flask or any other python web framework?

I mean when I open website A and click the link_1, logs should indicate that the click was made from website B.

I am not hoping for a full solution - just give me some start code/ tips of what to look for because I have no idea of how this could be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Folks writing Selenium tests come across
such issues often enough.

Use Chrome's dev tools [inspect network](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) tab to
see detailed outbound headers sent to the webserver.
Recreate those headers with your `requests` call.
Pay attention to the `Referer:` header, and also [UA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).